# How can I plot mixed integer problem result?

Tags: julia, julia-jump, julia-studio

I solved a linear bi-objective mixed integer problem and I want to plot the results. results include lines and points. for example

```
list=[([0.0; 583000.0], 0), ([190670.0; 149600.0], 0), ([69686.0, 385000.0], 1), ([33296.0, 484000.0], 1), ([136554.0, 2.38075e5], 1), ([24556.0, 503800.0], 0), ([47462.0, 437800.0], 1), ([129686.0, 253000.0], 1), ([164278.0, 178200.0], 1)]
```

In this list third point `([69686.0, 385000.0], 1)` second element `1` is determined that this point connected by a line to prior point `([190670.0; 149600.0], 0)` is connected to second point by a line.

I coded that as follow:

```
using  JuMP,Plots

list=[([0.0, 583000.0], 0), ([24556.0, 503800.0], 0), ([33296.0, 484000.0],1), ([47462.0, 437800.0], 1), ([69686.0, 385000.0], 1), ([129686.0, 253000.0], 1), ([136554.0, 23805.0], 1), ([164278.0, 178200.0], 1), ([190670.0, 149600.0], 0)]

x=zeros(1,1)
for i=1:size(list,1)
    x=[x;list[i][1][1]]
end
row=1
x = x[setdiff(1:end, row), :]

y=zeros(1,1)
for i=1:size(list,1)
    y=[y;list[i][1][2]]
end
row=1
y = y[setdiff(1:end, row), :]

for i=2:size(list,1)
    if list[i][2]==0
        plot(Int(x[i]),Int(y[i]),seriestype=:scatter)
        plot(Int(x[i+1]),Int(y[i+1]),seriestype=:scatter)
    end
    if list[i][2]==1
        plot(Int(x[i]),Int(y[i]))
        plot(Int(x[i+1]),Int(y[i+1]))
    end
end
```

but it is not worked. would you please help me. 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply push each line segment's x and y values to two separate arrays, `x` and `y` in the code below. After each line segment's values (i.e. x1 and x2 or y1 and y2) put a `NaN` into the arrays. This will prevent connecting a line segment to the next one if there should not be a connection. (for example, the case you see 1 and then a 0). And finally `plot(x, y)`.

The following code snippet does it. Note that `allx` and `ally` are used to hold all points regardless of connection status. You may want to exclude connected points from them. `x` and `y` holds connected line segments.

```
using Plots
x, y, allx, ally = Float64[], Float64[], Float64[], Float64[]

# iterate through list
for i = 1:length(list)-1
    if list[i+1][2] == 1
        # push x1 from the first point, x2 from the second and a `NaN`
        push!(x, list[i][1][1], list[i+1][1][1], NaN)
        # push y1, y2, `NaN`
        push!(y, list[i][1][2], list[i+1][1][2], NaN)
    end
    push!(allx, list[i][1][1])
    push!(ally, list[i][1][2])
end
push!(allx, list[end][1][1])
push!(ally, list[end][1][2])
# scatter all points
scatter(allx, ally)
# plot connections with markers
plot!(x, y, linewidth=2, color=:red, marker=:circle)
```

This should hopefully give you the plot you wanted.

---

If you happen to use `Gadfly.jl` instead of `Plots.jl`, you can get a similar plot with

```
using Gadfly
connectedpoints = layer(x=x, y=y, Geom.path, Geom.point, Theme(default_color="red"))
allpoints = layer(x=allx, y=ally, Geom.point)

plot(connectedpoints, allpoints)
```

---

As a side note if you plan to plot another series on top of a plot object already created, you should use `plot!` instead of `plot`.